# Is it possible to declare a variable without using "new" like "String" class

Tags: java, class, variables, instance, declaration

I want to achieve something like this. Declare and initialize a variable like those primitive data types.(Without having to use the new keyword)

```
MyClass myInstance = 123;
```

Similar to String. Only "String" type can do this and it's a class, too!

```
String myString = "A string!";
```

I want a way to declare some variable without using `new` like `new MyClass(123)`

**Thank you!**

Comment: Declare them without new, yes, initialize, on the other hand ...

Comment: Your question can be understood after I read a few times, I recommend reviewing your grammar or add more sentences so as to clarify what you want to say :)

Comment: You could define a method that creates an object. Then you can say `MyClass object = createMyClass(123)` instead of `MyClass object = new MyClass(123)` but that may not be an improvement in most cases.

Comment: Strings are special, because the JVM uses `new` for you. Primitive wrappers (Integer etc) are special because the compiler calls `valueOf` for you.

Comment: You are confused about the difference between "declaring a variable" and "creating an object".  You can do either one without doing the other.  But `new` is for creating an object, not for declaring a variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do it with custom classes.

The only classes that support such instantiation are `String` and the wrapper classes of the primitive types (`Integer`, `Boolean`, etc ...).

You could create instances of custom classes without the "new" if you use reflection, but then you'd be using `newInstance()` method of the `Class` class, which doesn't seem to be what you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

`123` is a number, `myInstance` is an object, they are not compatible, thus you cannot assign a `number` (or a `string`, or a `boolean`) to a variable of the `MyClass` type.

The only way this would be possible in the future is if Java would allow `operator overloading` (like C++ for example), for now you need to stick to `myInstance = new MyClass(123)`.